# Getting process list and hiding a specific app

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

How do I get a process list (in a popup button), and then when the user selects the application, can I hide/kill/minimize/quit the application?

Comment: That could be a very long pop-up menu. (Instruments demonstrates this quite well.) You might consider listing the processes in a table view instead.

Comment: i dont mind pop up just that whats the codes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`-[NSWorkspace runningApplications]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000391-SW7) will give you an `NSArray` of [`NSRunningApplication`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSRunningApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008799) instances representing currently-running processes. I'm not exactly sure what causes a program to be excluded from that list, but it does include any application that the user has launched from the Finder. It also includes a couple of things (the Finder itself, and the loginwindow process) that you don't want to mess with, as well as faceless applications.

You can filter those out using `filteredArrayWithPredicate:`; the objects you want to keep have an [`activationPolicy`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSRunningApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008799-CH1-SW6) of `NSApplicationActivationPolicyRegular`.

Once the array is filtered, you can search it, using `bundleIdentifier`, `bundleURL`, or `localizedName` to find the app you want. Then send `hide` or `terminate` as you like to that `NSRunningApplication` instance.

Apple has a sample project that demos all this, called [AppList](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/AppList/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008859).