# How to find a process?

Tags: macos, cocoa, process

I need to find some Process in the list of running process by its name.
I thought, that it's a very simple task, but no...

I read similar questions on this site but still don't found a simple answer.

[Process Manager Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/Process_Manager/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000208) allows to get list of only open [processes](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/Process_Manager/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000208-CH3g-TPXREF107).

This [solution](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/92971-bsd-processes-with-code.html) is not bad, but some-wise don't contains needed application in the result list, even if I see it in 'top'.

Anybody knows a working solution of such task?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you checkout following post (and associated comments):
http://jongampark.wordpress.com/2008/01/26/a-simple-objectie-c-class-for-checking-if-a-specific-process-is-running/

Also: [Getting process list and hiding a specific app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6531379/getting-process-list-and-hiding-a-specific-app)

Comment: On the other hand you can grab output from 'top' or similar command and try to get info from it. Check out the following post:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/412562/execute-a-terminal-command-from-a-cocoa-app/696942#696942

Comment: Thanks, to all for suggestions. I will use solution from first answer, with some modifications. 
As I remember NSWorkspace shows only user applications and do not see daemons, unfortunately. And I wonder - why cocoa, or other framework don't implements a class, that provides possibility to get access to all kind of running processes.